# CyanogenMod 12 dialer calls but no sound

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I am an avid CyanogenMod user and I have many reasons why. I constantly use the previous CyanogenMod without issue. However, upon moving to the new CyanogenMod 12 for my LG Optimus G Pro (E980), I can't place or receive calls properly. My dailer works as it should, but as soon as you place the call, you hear nothing. However, the phone still is making a call to whom you dialed. It will cause the other persons phone to ring, or my phone will ring if i am called, but I cannot hear anyone and no one can hear me. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!